# Django Populating multiple forms with multiple objects

Tags: django

I have a model called Question  and this model allow users to create new questions.
A user creates 10 question . How can I populate 10 forms with the question inside? Because I know I can populate  a form with single object but when I try to populate 10 objects .
The reason I want to populate 10 objects is to allow the user to edit his question

How could this be done?

thank you ,

I receive this error

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

forms

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question',)
```

views

```
def DisplayAll(request):
    q = Question.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    form = QuestionForm(instance=q)
    return render(request,'question.html',{'form':form })
```

forms.py

```
{% for f in form %}
{{form}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/)

> A formset is a layer of abstraction to work with multiple forms on the
>   same page. It can be best compared to a data grid.